# copy a selected file in a subdirectory and preserve directory structure

Tags: windows

I want to copy selected files in a sub directory from the source folder to a destination folder, at the same time, preserve the directory structure.

#### Source

- source_dir

  - sub1

    - file_1
    - file_2
  - sub2

    - file 3

#### Destination

- dest_dir

  - sub1

    - file1

How do I issue one command to do that?  I tried robocopy

```
robocopy c:\source_dir c:\dest_dir sub1\file_1 /s
```

robocopy complained that the file parameter (Parameter #3) is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
robocopy C:\source_dir C:\dest_dir /s /if file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: that should work except it scans all directory when I want file1 from a specific directory